# How do I show angularjs material validation for another model property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

Using angularjs and material, I want to be able to have a readonly textbox that displays the name for a selected object a user looks up (via a modal popup), but the textbox validation should show as required and fire off if a separate id property is not populated.  Here is an example [plnkr](http://www.plnkr.co/edit/pUVSOAZfWUxy388Tntnx?p=preview).

I was originally thinking that I could do this simply by adding a hidden field with an ng-model, name, and required attribute, it would create the associated form property for the field with required validator (which it does), and I would be able to show the validator on the readonly textbox like so:

```
<form name="myCtrl.myForm" novalidate>
  <input type="hidden" ng-model="myCtrl.id" name="id" required />
  <div layout="row">
    <md-input-container flex="50">
        <label>Selected Object</label>
        <input ng-model="myCtrl.selectedObject.selectedText" readonly />
        <div ng-messages="myCtrl.myForm.id.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">Please select an object.</div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
    <div>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button md-primary" ng-click="myCtrl.select($event)">
            <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                Select Object
            </md-tooltip>
            <md-icon>search</md-icon>
        </md-button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" type="submit">Submit</md-button>
  </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
vm.select = function(evt) {
  // Set the selected Object
  vm.selectedObject = { selectedText: "Object id 1 selected", id: 1 };
  // Set the associated ID
  vm.id = 1;

};
```

However, the `<div ng-message="required">Please select an object.</div>` never displays when the form is submitted and validation fires.  Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was typing up this question I had an idea - perhaps I should be creating a custom validator that I can apply to this input which references a separate property.  That appeared to do what I needed.  Here's the [plnkr](http://www.plnkr.co/edit/QpnGSyRAfAXiSwLavgss?p=preview) and here's the directive:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMessages', 'ngMaterial'])
  .directive('requiredOther', RequiredOther);

function RequiredOther() {

    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            requiredOtherValue: "=requiredOther"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$validators.requiredOther = function(modelValue) {
                return scope.requiredOtherValue !== undefined && scope.requiredOtherValue !== null && scope.requiredOtherValue !== '';
            };

            scope.$watch("requiredOtherValue", function() {
                ngModel.$validate();
            });
        }
    };
}
```

This is the updated HTML:

```
<form name="myCtrl.myForm" novalidate>
  <input type="hidden" ng-model="myCtrl.id" />
  <div layout="row">
    <md-input-container flex="50">
        <label>Selected Object</label>
        <input name="id" ng-model="myCtrl.selectedObject.selectedText" readonly required-other="myCtrl.id" />
        <div ng-messages="myCtrl.myForm.id.$error">
            <div ng-message="requiredOther">Please select an object.</div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
    <div>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button md-primary" ng-click="myCtrl.select($event)">
            <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
                Select Object
            </md-tooltip>
            <md-icon>search</md-icon>
        </md-button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" type="submit">Submit</md-button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The `required-other="myCtrl.id"` directive references the id property and watches for changes and fires off validation on change:
I guess I don't really need the hidden input field anymore either.